# Python: printed object has a type but returned object is NoneType?

Tags: python, list, typeerror, numpy-ndarray, nonetype

I have a function that returns a tuple containing a NumPy array and a list. At the end of the function I print out the array and the list and both look correct. Then I print their types and these also look correct. But when I return them, I get a NoneType error. I am very confused as to why this is happening. Code below. `adjust_param` is a helper function. The TypeError is asserted in the return line of `optimize_theta`.

```
def adjust_param(R, delta, i, theta):
    thetaplus = theta.copy()
    thetaminus = theta.copy()
    thetaplus[i*2] += delta
    thetaplus[i*2+1] += delta
    thetaminus[i*2] -= delta
    thetaminus[i*2+1] -= delta    
    y = Remp(q_data, labels, R, num_samples, theta)
    yplus = Remp(q_data, labels, R, num_samples, thetaplus)
    yminus = Remp(q_data, labels, R, num_samples, thetaminus)
    if (yplus < y and yplus < yminus and yplus != -1):
        return thetaplus, yplus
    elif (yminus < y and yminus < yplus and yminus != -1):
        return thetaminus, yminus
    else:
        return theta, y
```

```
def optimize_theta(N, R, delta, i, theta, risk):
    if N == 0:
        print("Theta : " + str(type(theta)))
        print("= " + str(theta))
        print()
        print("Risk : " + str(type(risk)))
        print("= " + str(risk))
        return theta, risk
    else:
        theta_new, risk_new = adjust_param(R, delta, i, theta)
        if i == (len(theta)/2)-1:
            #print("N = " +  str(N-1))
            #print("theta = " + str(theta))
            risk_copy = risk.copy()
            risk_copy.append(risk_new)
            optimize_theta(N-1, R, delta, 0, theta_new, risk_copy)
        else:
            optimize_theta(N, R, delta, i+1, theta_new, risk)
```

Output:

```
Theta : <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
= [0.85885111 0.86066499 0.47482528 0.13555158 0.87249245 0.02604654
 0.2906744  0.34618303]

Risk : <class 'list'>
= [0.6273510217403618]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-307-8b43b528fee2> in <module>
----> 1 theta, risk = optimize_theta(N, R, delta, 0, theta0, [])

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

Any insight would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: your `else` part does not return anything explicitly, so it returns `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must explicitly return results in the `else` section in optimize_theta.

```
def optimize_theta(N, R, delta, i, theta, risk):
    if N == 0:
        print("Theta : " + str(type(theta)))
        print("= " + str(theta))
        print()
        print("Risk : " + str(type(risk)))
        print("= " + str(risk))
        return theta, risk
    else:
        theta_new, risk_new = adjust_param(R, delta, i, theta)
        if i == (len(theta)/2)-1:
            #print("N = " +  str(N-1))
            #print("theta = " + str(theta))
            risk_copy = risk.copy()
            risk_copy.append(risk_new)
            return optimize_theta(N-1, R, delta, 0, theta_new, risk_copy)
        else:
            return optimize_theta(N, R, delta, i+1, theta_new, risk)
```